# Syntax error on my mysql trigger code. ERROR 1064 (42000):

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have below trigger code but It give me error. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

```
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `user_has_voice_queues_rt_update`;
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    TRIGGER `user_has_voice_queues_rt_update` 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON `user_has_voice_queues_rt` 
    FOR EACH ROW begin 
    if(new.pause='0') then  
    Set new.penalty = (select max(penalty) from user_has_voice_queues_rt) + 1; 
    end if;
```

Comment: You need to tell us what the *complete* error message was. The code you posted is missing an `END` but I assume that's just a typo.

Comment: what error you are facing ?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: It's that your _exact_ query? Is the semi-colon symbol at `+ 1 ;` suppose to be there?

Comment: Yes this is my exact query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `user_has_voice_queues_rt_update`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `user_has_voice_queues_rt_update` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `user_has_voice_queues_rt` 
FOR EACH ROW begin 
if(new.pause='0') then  
Set new.penalty = (select max(penalty) from user_has_voice_queues_rt) + 1; 
end if;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```